# Migrate Ubuntu 16.04 to larger drive and convert to BTRFS and add swap

Tags: ubuntu, grub, btrfs, ext2

I'm able to dd my Ubuntu installation from an SD card to my finally-arrived SSD and boot it, but as soon as I resize the partition (using gparted from a livecd), it stops booting. I've tried reinstalling grub2 and nothing. It works again when I dd from the SD again, but I can't get the partition expanded. I'm using ext2, but I want to convert it to btrfs and also add a swap partition.

Comment: Is your SD a bootable? Does it have a 'live' system on it, or a regular install? A 'live' system is a special case with a compressed read-only root file-system. For you SSD, you probably don't want a 'live' system, you want a regular Linux install.

Comment: It is a regular install. Since this post I've expanded by partition, but btrfs doesn't work and I can't find a decent guide to make it work as my boot partition

Comment: I use btrfs a lot as my root file-system, but I still use a smaller ext4 as my boot partition (containing the kernel, initrd, grub or extlinux). Booting directly from btrfs is still not fully supported, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a 2GB ext4 boot partition on the SSD, then copying your kernel and initrd into that.

If you want to just copy your SD rootfs onto the SSD, I don't think dd is the best approach. I do something like:

```
mkdir /bind
mount -o bind / /bind
cd /bind
cp -a . /path/to/new/root/subvol/
```

Then you will have to edit the new fstab to make sense,

```
LABEL={ssd-btrfs-label}  /  btrfs noatime,subvol={new-root-subvol}
LABEL={ssd-boot-label}   /boot ext4 noatime
```

then, boot to the new rootfs by booting from your sd, and editing the kernel command-line to add/change:

```
 root=LABEL={btrfs-filesystem-label}
 rootflags=noatime,subvol={new-root-subvol}
```

After booting into your new system, you can use grub-install to install the boot-loader properly on the SSD.

Depending on your kernel and hardware, you can tweak performance with other mount options:

```
 lazytime,nodatacow
```